# Mathematica: summing over n abstract indices

Tags: list-manipulation

This probably has a one line answer, but I'm totally stuck.

I have two tensors, i.e. two objects that depend on NN abstract indices which i've labelled `i[m] (m=1,...,NN)`. I want to keep NN general for now. Each index `i[m]` ranges over the values `{1,2}`. I want to sum over all the `i[m]`s, i.e.

```
Sum[a[i[1],...,i[NN]] * b[i[1],...,i[NN]], {i[1],1,2},{i[2],1,2},...,{i[NN],1,2}]
```

The only problem I have is finding a general expression that generates the "array" {i[1],1,2},{i[2],1,2},...,{i[NN],1,2} in the summation. I tried Table but that gives me an array of the form

```
{{i[1],1,2},{i[2],1,2},...,{i[NN],1,2}}
```

and I can't get rid of the outer brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is firstly `Sequence` to get rid of the outer parenthesis. It's usage is fairly simple `f[Sequence[3,4]]` evaluates to  `f[3,4]`, so if you apply it to a list the elements end up being the arguments. The second thing you need to do is get the transformation into a sequence to actually evaluate `Sum` has attribute `HoldAll` so if you just write it out it won't evaluate, you need to put `Evaluate` around it:

```
Attributes[Sum]
{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

indicelist = Table[i[n], {n, 1, 3}]
iteratorlist = {#, 1, 2} & /@ indicelist;

 Sum[a[Sequence @@ indicelist], Evaluate[Sequence @@ iteratorlist]]
```

Comment: The use of `Sequence[]` is not too hard to bypass: `Sum[a @@ indicelist, ##] & @@ iteratorlist`.

Comment: @J.M. I wanted to use sequence because the question specifically mentions "and I can't get rid of the outer brackets.", which i think Sequence solves directly, while function application seems an indirect method of doing this. I used Evaluate rather then passing to highlight the problem arising from not having evaluation of the argument. All that being said, your solution is indeed much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

I have no confidence that I actually understand this question, but acl tried to explain it to me and based on that I think perhaps all you need is: `Total[a b, -1]`.

```
{a, b} // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Total[a b, -1]
```

> A I + B J + C K + D L + E M + F N + G O + H P

Comment: ah yes, blame it on me if it's wrong :) (joking)

Comment: @acl hardly; I make no claim that I understood *you* either. ;-)

Comment: I'm only joking. You understood me perfectly well, so it *is* my fault if this is wrong :)